# How to force a time series to plot on the whole year, when data is only a few months

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, time-series

I have multiple time series each having a different beginning and end time. When I plot them using pandas and matplotlib I get nice graphs beginning from t0 and ending at tx for each individual series. I know that I cannot plot different length series in one plot, but i would like to at least view them with the months lining up.

For example, say I have two series: 1, begins April and ends September, 2 begins February and ends December.

How do visualize them so that each series is plotted on a yearly graph (Jan to Dec) even though the data does not span those dates? I want to see them one above the other they lining up according to months.

I have it like this so far, with xlim=('jan', 'dec'), but I just get blank plots

```
for dfl in dfl_list[0:2]:
       dfl.plot(x='DateTime', y=['VWCmax', 'VWCmin'],
            ax=p1, fontsize=15, xlim=('Jan', 'Dec'))
       p1.set_title('Time vs VWC', fontsize=15)
       p1.set_ylabel('VWC (%)  ' + '{}'.format(imei), fontsize=15)
       p1.set_xlabel('Time Stamp', fontsize=15)
```

I've also tried xticks instead of xlim, but I also get blank plots.

Comment: Might seem janky- but if all else fails, would adding a blank record with that date be a viable option? Do something like this in psuedo code `if min(month(date)) != 'January' then Create_Blank_Record()`

Comment: Humn, perhaps, its worth a try, if there are no better solutions. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. By default the axes will extend to show all data, so plotting two different curves in one plot will show both curves entirely. What you are asking for is hence the default behaviour. If you have problems getting there, you need to provide a [mcve] of the issue, i.e. a code one can copy, paste and run to see the undesired result and help you rectifying it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I was having was that I thought that the argument for xlim could be be the strings 'Jan', and 'Dec', this ended up returning blank graphs because pyplot did not know how to fit a graph on string type. the solution is that xlim has to be passed datetime arguments:

```
for dfl in dfl_list[0:2]:
    dfl.plot(x='DateTime', y=['VWCmax', 'VWCmin'],
       ax=p1, fontsize=15, xlim=(datetime(2017,1,1), datetime(2017,12,31))
    p1.set_title('Time vs VWC', fontsize=15)
    p1.set_ylabel('VWC (%)  ' + '{}'.format(imei), fontsize=15)
    p1.set_xlabel('Time Stamp', fontsize=15)
```